# Error while compiling with javac in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, compilation, javac

I'm trying to compile some software in Ubuntu to run it. I downloaded it and I saw there was a compile.bat file. I tried to run it with Wine but I get some errors. After that, I create a compile.sh file with same commands as compile.bat file. These commands are:

```
javac -extdirs lib/ core/*.java
javac -extdirs lib/ movement/*.java
javac -extdirs lib/ report/*.java
javac -extdirs lib/ routing/*.java
javac -extdirs lib/ gui/*.java
javac -extdirs lib/ input/*.java
javac -extdirs lib/ applications/*.java
javac -extdirs lib/ interfaces/*.java
```

I tried to run the .sh script but I get this error:

```
root@vbox:/media/sf_shared/one_1.4.1# ./compile.sh 
error: option -extdirs not allowed with target 11
error: option -extdirs not allowed with target 11
error: option -extdirs not allowed with target 11
error: option -extdirs not allowed with target 11
error: option -extdirs not allowed with target 11
error: option -extdirs not allowed with target 11
error: option -extdirs not allowed with target 11
error: option -extdirs not allowed with target 11
```

These are my java versions:

```
javac 11.0.4
/usr/bin/javac
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
/usr/bin/java
```

It seems like "extdirs" option doesn't exist. However, it is listed as a javac option:

```
-extdirs <dirs>              Override location of installed extensions

root@vbox:/media/sf_shared/one_1.4.1# javac -extdirs
error: -extdirs requires an argument
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

How can I solve it? Any help will be usefull since I don't know too much about Java.

Comment: Check [`here`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__CROSS-COMPILATIONOPTIONSFORJAVAC-7D3D83C3). `extdirs` can only be used when compiling for versions prior to JDK 9.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Thanks! Do you know some workaround for extdirs in JDK11?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but maybe `-cp` can help you as someone suggested [`here`](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/issues/74) ...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I changed my default java to 1.8 and it worked. I will also try your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to java1.8 solve the problem as @seconf said.